# Join two flv files with PHP and ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

On my website I'm using phpmotion to convert videos into FLV files.
What I want to do is that after the successful conversion of any new FLV file add short FLV file at the beginning.

So, I need FFMPEG command in PHP which will join the file 1.flv (intro file) with 2.flv (successful converted file) and as a result create final.flv

I tried with:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.flv -i 2.flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy final.flv
```

But without result.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What happens or doesn't happen? What error messages do you get?

Comment: @Pekka - practically nothing, a video that lasts two seconds and a black display

Comment: And 1.flv and 2.flv are both valid movie files? You are 100% sure?

Comment: maybe the two flv files are not compatible... @Sergio can you post the output of mediainfo for both files ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, you have to seperate audio and video to raw files at first, join them then again convert back to flv

```
mkfifo temp1.a
mkfifo temp1.v
mkfifo temp2.a
mkfifo temp2.v
mkfifo all.a
mkfifo all.v
ffmpeg -i 1.flv -vn -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 - > temp1.a < /dev/null &
ffmpeg -i 2.flv -vn -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 - > temp2.a < /dev/null &
ffmpeg -i 1.flv -an -f yuv4mpegpipe - > temp1.v < /dev/null &
{ ffmpeg -i 2.flv -an -f yuv4mpegpipe - < /dev/null | tail -n +2 > temp2.v ; } &
cat temp1.a temp2.a > all.a &
cat temp1.v temp2.v > all.v &
ffmpeg -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i all.a \
       -f yuv4mpegpipe -i all.v \
       -sameq -y output.flv
rm temp[12].[av] all.[av]
```

Comment: This one is working for me and, as I can see, is taken from [FFmpeg FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use [mencoder](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/MPlayer) to merge two files.

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -o c:\video.flv c:\a.flv c:\b.flv
```